# Tests of a non-angular page with protractor cannot click on a link element

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to visit a non-angular page, like google.com and then clicking a link on that page.
I am using protractor with the cucumber plugin.
My cucumber feature looks like this:

```
Feature: Google

Scenario: Google test
Given I visit google
When I click the link
Then result
```

The step definitions look like this:

```
Given('I visit google', function(callback) {
    browser.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
        .then(callback);
});
When('I click the link', function() {
   browser.driver.findElement(by.linkText('Images')).click();
});
Then('result', function() {

});
```

When running protractor the page opens, but the link is not clicked (Google image search is not loading)

How do I get the link clicked to be redirected to google image search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is extra brace at the end of click();
Also, please the click might happen as protractor scripts execute faster as they are asynchronous. 
Give some sleep and check, this is for only testing purpose as ExpectedConditions to be used for explicit waits :

Update the snippet as below and give a try :

```
When('I click the link', function() {
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.linkText("Images"))).then(()=>{
      browser.driver.findElement(by.linkText('Images')).click();
      browser.sleep(3000);
    });
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The extra brace was a typo in my question. The tests are shown as passed before the page has even loaded, the sleep call doesn't help. How can I wait for the site to have finished loading?

Comment: You can use expected conditions, like below : browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("#element_id"))), 5000, 'Loading Homeview Failed'); Here browser will wait, till element_id element is visible, else will throw the error -  Loading Homeview Failed

Comment: Refer this url : https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: You mean browser.driver.findElement instead of element, right? This doesn't work either (I added the line right before the findElement in "When"). I am getting the following error: "Unable to locate element: Images"

Comment: I updated how to use using .then, please try with that snippet!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.